# ToWorkBook error in Powershell

Tags: .net, excel, powershell

I'm running a script in Powershell, which worked last week, but for some reason isn't today, and i've not changed anything. The line that seems to be the issue is below, as when I take it out, I don't get the error (but it obviously doesn't produce the spreadsheet without this line):

```
[InfExcelExtension.ToExcel]::ToWorkBook($DS,$FileDest);
```

The error is in screenshot attached. [image]

On face value of this line, do you know what I might be missing? I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Have you got sensible values for `$DS` and `$FileDest` parameters? The error claims that one is empty.

Comment: Ah, such a silly oversight from me. There was a stray comma in my filedest path. Cheers